# POSIX access and groups identifiers

Tags: linux, unix, posix

Could you explain me how *nix checks permissions on files (POSIX access)? Or give a link. I found a lot of links but questions remained.

As I understand a process has six (r|e|s)(uid|gid) identifiers. And there is the process supplementary groups list. It is calculated based on the real user supplementary groups list when a new process executed (plus the process gid). But changing of any gid identifier doesn't affect on that list. You need call initgroups().

A file has the uid, gid and the permissions with 3 groups of bits (classes): "owner", "group" and "other".

And algorithm is as follows:

- If the euid of the process is 0 it is the root and it have any permission. Else we need define the bits class.
- If the process euid = the file uid it is "owner"
- Then we check does the process correspond the file group and use "group" or "other" class depended on the result.

How I understand in the last action we just look is the file gid included to the process supplementary groups list. Is this correct? Then I don't understand why do we need (r|e|s)gid identifiers? They are not used in the access checking and they don't affect directly of the supplementary groups list.